How to resolve relative module imports in Python when calling from an arbitrarily located script?
I have a submodule that I would like to use. The structure of my project can be boiled down to
*/
├── samples/
├── scripts/
│   └── script.py  # contains "from ai_model import AiModel"
├── model/  # submodule, branch=main
    ├── models/  # with __init__.py
    │   ├── base_model.py
    │   └── ai_model.py  # contains "from .base_model import BaseModel"
    ├── util/  # with __init__.py
    └── data/  # with __init__.py
    ...

I execute my script.py from the within the scripts directory. I managed to add util, models and so on using
import sys
from pathlib import Path

models_module = Path('../model/models/').resolve()
sys.path.insert(0, models_module.__str__())

util_module = Path('../model/').resolve()
sys.path.insert(0, util_module.__str__())

..

However, the code currently breaks at (high chance other parts of the submodule are also affected by this issue)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\example\Project\scripts\script.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ai_model import AiModel
  File "C:\Users\example\Project\model\models\ai_model.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base_model import BaseModel
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I do not want to modify the source code contained in the submodule. I can add __init__.py files if necessary though.

This question is similar to: Yet another Python Relative import mishap. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Run as module from the parent directory (containing scripts and model). python -m scripts.script. No modification of sys.path required.

In your script.py, modify the imports to use absolute imports:
from model.models.ai_model import AiModel
# Same for util and data
# for example: from model.util import foo

Run your project in the root directory using python -m scripts.script.
Now running the script as a module treats the scripts directory as part of a package, which allows relative imports like model.models.ai_model to resolve correctly.
